# C# Generic type constraint muddle

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I am having trouble with a generic type constraint. I have the below method, and im struggling to pass anything into the childSegments parameter, the first parameter i can get round.

```
private void FillSegment<T, TT>(BaseSegment<T> segment, IEnumerable<BaseSegment<TT>> childSegments)
        where T : class
        where TT : class
    {}
```

TT is of type class, but the list im trying to pass in, should be a combination of different classes not just a single class type, that's the wall i am hitting. I could just pass in this list:

`List<BaseSegment<Lead>> l = new List<BaseSegment<Lead>>();`

but like i said, i need to pass in multiple classes, i have a LeadSegment, AccountSegment, ContactSegment etc (which implement `BaseSegment<T>`).

The ideal scenario would be something like this:

```
List<BaseSegment<T>> lst = new List<BaseSegment<T>>();
lst.Add(LeadSegment);
lst.Add(AccountSegment);
lst.Add(ContactSegment);
```

..and pass that, but you cannot create a list with a `<T>` type within a method or outside i believe

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, if all you want is having classes that derive from BaseSegment, then you just need to add this constraint to your T (like that: `where T : BaseSegment`)

Comment: why not create the list? inside your FillSegment method you can do List<TT> lst, or List<BaseSegment<T>> lst. Just call FillSegment<T, BaseSegment>(..., lst)

Answer (score 1):

Make `BaseSegment` a non-generic abstract class (you don't ever instantiate `BaseSegment` directly do you?). Your signature for `FillSegment` could then look like this:

```
private void FillSegment<TParent>(TParent parent, IEnumerable<BaseSegment> children)
    where TParent : BaseSegment
```

This enables you to consume the method like this:

```
var parent = new SomeParentSegment(); // SomeParentSegment derives from BaseSegment
var children = new List<BaseSegment>();
children.Add(new LeadSegment()); // LeadSegment derives from BaseSegment
children.Add(new AccountSegment()); // AccountSegment derives from BaseSegment
children.Add(new ContactSegment()); // ContactSegment derives from BaseSegment

FillSegment(parent, children);
```

Note that this allows `children` to be of the same type as `parent`, given that both instances derive from `BaseSegment`.

Comment: Thanks for the the responses and i understand the above as it it makes perfect sense, however, in the fill segment method i am calling another method to a class in a different library, the reason i have a `T` in my `BaseSegment` is, the other library needs this type to dynamically select a entity from the entity framework as i dynamically pass in a EF context. The concrete segment's all implement a Func which i use to set a primary key to `Func<T, Guid> JoinFunc { get { return (x) => x.LeadID; } }` and then this is used in that library. I just need a way of building that list.

Comment: I think you could create a concrete (non-abstract) and generic implementation to "talk" to the other library, like `GenericSegment<T> where T : BaseSegment` on top of the above, you should be able to supply the other library a GenericSegment<LeadSegment>.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble following what you are wanting to do, but I think you want to make your constraints

```
where TT : T
```

or...

```
where TT : BaseSegment<T>
```

Both of these scenarios enable your "Ideal scenario" above; but without a further understanding...